# Why are shortcuts in my xcode not working after upgrade macos

Tags: xcode, macos

I had several xcode extensions, which were activated by certain keyboard shortcuts.

It worked fine and dandy, and then i upgraded my macos to macos bigsur

and they stopped working.

How do I turn it back on?

I went through the manuals of the extensions and redid the steps they gave to activate, and it still did not work.

Comment: which Xcode version do you use and it happens just for Xcode or any other applications confused as well ?

Comment: Xcode 12.0, and yes just xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the extensions stopped being compatible with macOS BigSur, after receiving an update, they started working

Answer (score 0):

- Go to    `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/KeyBindings/`  it is supposed to be a Keybindings profile such as default or "lena" for example.. Let`s say it lena:
- It is supposed to be there `lena.idekeybindings` file open this XML file and check if something wrong with your shortcuts. If it is already deleted or changed with default one, You lost your shortcuts. :(

Note : I always keep a copy of that XML file which has my unique short cuts. Also i use Karabiner to keep other shortcuts for my MacOS.